Python Function Variable Names Rather Than Values
I have a dataframe. I need to create a new column if certain conditions are met. I've created logic in a variable.
Example:
logic1 = '''
unit_sales > 1000 and total_sales >= 1000000
'''

logic2 = '''
unit_sales < 100 and total_sales < 10
'''

I've created two new columns:
df[['Change','Value']] = None

Then based on my logic the value is set or ignored:
df.loc[df.eval(logic1),'Change'] = 'logic1'
df.loc[df.eval(AP2_on),'Value'] = 500

This works great. I have a new value based on my logic and a field that tells me which logic made the modification. The issue is I want to make this into a function so I don't have to repeat code. Something like this:
    def function(logic, value):
        df.loc[df.eval(logic),'Change'] = logic 
#----I need the variable name (i.e. 'logic1' and not the variable value#
        df.loc[df.eval(logic),'Value'] = value
        return df

    df = function(logic1, 500)

I've searched a while and can't seem to find anything that will help.
Any thoughts?

You should be using a dict so you can pass d['logic1']  to your function.

Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Right.  ANY TIME you find yourself creating names like xxx1 and xxx2, etc, you should replace that with a list or a dictionary.

variables shouldn't contain program data in their names. A variable's name is for the person reading the code. Instead, use an appropriate data type to associate the string with the other object. So, a list of tuple objects could work, e.g. logics = [('logic1', 'unit_sales > 1000 and total_sales >= 1000000'), ...] or perhaps a dict: logics = {'logic1':  'unit_sales > 1000 and total_sales >= 1000000', ...}

Parameters are passed by value. It's not possible to get the name that was used in the argument (it might not be a named variable, it could be any expression).
Use a dictionary that maps logic names to expressions. Then pass the key to the function, and use this to look up the logic by name, and save that name in the dataframe.
logic_dict = {
    'logic1': '''unit_sales > 1000 and total_sales >= 1000000''',
    'logic2': '''unit_sales < 100 and total_sales < 10'''
}

def function(logic, value):
    df.loc[df.eval(logic_dict[logic]), ['Change', 'Value']] = [logic, value] 
    return df

df = function('logic1', 500)


I'm getting a warning: 'VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
return asarray(a).ndim'    Any ideas?

I'm not sure why. Does the warning go away if you split it into two assignments, like in your original code?
